# FactoryGirl has_many through relationship with custom attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, factory-bot, rspec-rails, has-many-through

I am getting trouble to get this FactoryGirl association set up correctly.

I have my models as follows:

```
class ProductList < ActiveRecord::Base  
  has_many :product_list_items   
  has_many :product_variations, :through => :product_list_items
end

class ProductVariation < ActiveRecord::Base    
  has_many :product_list_items
  has_many :product_lists, :through => :product_list_items
end

class ProductListItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :product_list_id, :product_variation_id, :quantity

  belongs_to :list
  belongs_to :product_variation
end
```

My factories are as follows:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :product_list do
    sequence(:name) { |n| "Product List {n}" }
    description "Product List Description"
    user    
    after :create do |p|
      p.product_variations << FactoryGirl.create(:product_variation)
    end
  end
end

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :product_list_item do
    association :product_list
    association :product_variation
    quantity { rand(1..30) }
  end
end

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :product_variation do
    sequence(:sku) { |n| "product_sku_#{n}" }
    product
    price {"#{ rand(1..30) }.#{ rand(10..99) }"}
    currency "USD"
  end
end
```

Now when I create the product list factory as

```
product_list = FactoryGirl.create(:product_list)
```

and inspect the product_list_item for product_list I get **quantity = nil**

```
product_list.product_list_items.first.inspect

#<ProductListItem id: 8, product_list_id: 8, product_variation_id: 8, quantity: nil, created_at: "2013-09-17 04:35:58", updated_at: "2013-09-17 04:35:58">
```

Can someone please point out where I went wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I cannot see that you use the product_list_item factory anywhere. Is it called somewhere?

Comment: It is used in some controller and the test fails as it has nil value there.

Comment: Could you explain this further? Normally factories are only used in tests.

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to use `create_list` in combination with **transient attributes** accessed by the evaluator to build multiple custom records, like this:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :post do
    sequence(:title) { |n| "a title #{n}" }

    factory :post_with_comments do
      transient do
        comments %w(fantastic awesome great)
      end

      after(:create) do |post, evaluator|
        FactoryGirl.create_list(:comment, evaluator.comments.count, post: post) do |instance|
          instance.text = evaluator.comments.shift
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

(or `pop` instead of `shift` for a reverse order), which can be called as

```
title = 'Post Title'
names = %w(well wtf crap)
model = FactoryGirl.create(:post_with_comments, title: title, comments: names.clone)
```